# Create an ordered set in F#

Tags: f#, set

I need some help to find out how to create an ordered set in F#, or at least create a set and then order it. Documentation on the topic is not very clear.

Comment: Do you want to write your own sorted set implementation or use an existing one?

Comment: I'd rather use a built-in one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set implements IEnumerable interface so you can use functions from Seq module on sets.

```
let set = Set.ofList [ 9; 2; 5; 7; 5 ]
let orderedSeq = Seq.sort set
```

By design Set is something that is not excatly sorted collection but you can query to the set to retrive its elements in specific order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is it possible to create a mutable empty set and then add values to it?

Comment: Functional way would be to declare initial value as an empty set `Set.empty` and then construct new sets on top of it by `Set.add`. Look at the signature of that function, it returns new set with added element.

Comment: There is a lot of resources about different collection types and how to use them. Please read here: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/

Comment: Note that sets are already sorted, but the documentation doesn't make this completely clear.

Comment: Thank you guys, the resource you linked is very helpful, I'll take the time to read it carefully.

Comment: Use HashSet if you need a mutable set.

Comment: @kvb I don't think sets are sorted. At least when I do a set difference, it returns items in a different order than when created off a sequence.

Comment: @Abel - could you give an example?  Sets are internally represented as search trees (which is why then need the type of their element to support comparison).  But note that they are ordered based on their elements' values, not based on insertion order.

Comment: @kvb, perhaps the simplest example would be something like `[9;5;4;3;7;8;9;4;9;1] |> Set.ofSeq |> Set.difference <| (Set.ofSeq [1;4])`. On my machine it returns `[3; 5; 7; 8; 9]`, which is a different order than the original sequence. [This page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fsharp/fsharp_sets.htm) explains briefly that the order is undetermined, but whether it is deterministic, or stable, I don't know. But this seems to match your last comment. The OP mentioned "ordered", which is not the same as "sorted". It take that as "the order is preserved", and sorting would change the order.

Comment: I actually happened upon this when finding out that I assumed in my code that the order (of the seq) was preserved. It wasn't. Using F# 4.0's `Seq.except` kept the order. I think I understand your point, though I doubt that the sort-order of a set is necessarily the same between versions. Though it may be a stable order within one F# version (none of this becomes clear from reading the docs). Finally, I think it is best to think of a set as in the mathematical sense, for which the [order is irrelevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)).

Comment: @Abel - The ambiguity around the word "order" makes it confusing, but I believe that the original question really was about sorting, not about maintaining the order that elements were inserted (especially given that the accepted answer uses `Seq.sort`).  The documentation for the `set` type says: "Immutable sets based on binary trees, where comparison is the F# structural comparison function", so I think it's pretty clear that the set's elements are stored in sorted order based on the F# `compare` operator, and won't change between versions.

Comment: @kvb, thanks, that makes sense. Though I wonder why my algo didn't work (which is too large to repeat), I should look into my implementation of `IComparable`, which seems the likely cause of the order becoming unpredictable.